# How to retrieve a title attribute from an image using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
container = page_soup.findAll("img",{"class":"logo"})
container[0]
<img alt="GIGABYTE" class="logo" src="//c1.neweggimages.com/brandimage//Brand1314.gif" title="GIGABYTE">
</img>
```

How can I scrape the world "GIGABYTE" as text from the above?

I am a beginner at this.

---

```
container = page_soup.findAll("img",{"class":"logo"})

container[0]  and the Result => img alt="GIGABYTE" class="logo" src="//c1.neweggimages.com/brandimage//Brand1314.gif" title="GIGABYTE">
```

Now I can scrape the word `"GIGABYTE"` as text from the above result. I am a beginner at this. plz, help.

sorry this is the question

Comment: Can you give an example of a page containing the word you want to scrape?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. here is the link: https://www.newegg.com/gigabyte-radeon-rx-5700-xt-gv-r57xtgaming-oc-8gd/p/N82E16814932208?Item=N82E16814932208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that webscraping goes against the terms of service of that website, however I believe you're free to do whatever you'd like with the html if you obtain it manually.

`soup.find_all('img', class_='logo')[0]['title']`

Comment: one more thing I would like to ask you. Can you help me with the below issue?. It will be a lifesaver. I searched online but did not get any solution

I would like to scrape the different handset's dimension form this page: https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung-phones-9.php   which is inside in the links of phone. 

 for that, I need a scraper that will go into these links and scrape the data from me. I am stuck here for two days.  just point me the right direction so that i can figure it out from an example or tutorial.

Comment: That website appears to permit webscraping. Once you have a soup of that web page named `soup`, getting a list of the links is simply `phone_section = soup.find('div', class_='makers'); [a['href'] for a in phone_section.find_all('a')]`.